# svn: turn exported tree into working copy

Tags: svn, export, working-copy

In order to quickly deploy our app to a new remote server, we exported our branch to a local directory, zipped it, then unzipped it on the new server.

Now, we want to turn that exported copy (which is an exact replica of the branch in the repo) into a working copy. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the export is simply a copy of the branch, why not just check out from the branch?

Of course, I've noticed that as long as all of the subversion meta files are present, you can connect a project back to the repository.  If you have a subversion client on your server and aren't afraid to work with the command line, you could probably try a "svn status" to see if you can connect to the repository.

Comment: Well, the issue is that doing a checkout on the server takes exorbitantly long, which is why we push a zipped copy up to the server.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use the following workflow:

1. Export a specific revision from repo and upload it to my webserver. So I have a **live version**.
2. When I exported the revision, I create a tag indicating that this version is live now (e.g. `live_from_xxyyzz` where `xxyyzz` is the date of upload)
3. When I have to do any changes, I change locally, check them in, then do a new export (i.e. go to step 1)

Doing so, there's absolutely no need to turn an exported version back to a working copy since you have your tags that you can trust.

On the other hand, you can simply take your live version (that one on the remote server) and **copy it over your working directory**. If something's different, you will notice it (as well as missing files or new files).

**Edit:**

When your exported version shall become a working copy, you have a little trouble using svn: svn (currently) needs an `.svn` folder of the checked out working copy. These `.svn` folders hold the versioning information. To put the whole exported version under version control, you'd have to create (and populate) these folders (i.e. copy them from a real working copy into the exported version).

From Subversion 1.7 on, there will be a [centralized metadata storage](http://subversion.wandisco.com/component/content/article/1/44.html) what means that all the versioning related files are stored in *one* folder per working copy (like for example Git does). That would make solving your problem easier, but for now, I see no other alternative but to copy the `.svn` folders from a working copy as described above (except really checking out the branch, of course).

Comment: I want the exported copy to become a working copy of my branch so that I can do svn update to pull the latest changes. The reason I bring an exported copy is because the branch is huge and takes forever to checkout on the server.